# awk: print lines after match to end of file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to parse a usage message like:

```
Usage:
  docker-compose [-f <arg>...] [options] [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
  docker-compose -h|--help
...
Commands:
  build              Build or rebuild services
  bundle             Generate a Docker bundle from the Compose file
...
```

to grab the `Command` names only. So I'm looking to skip all lines up to and including the `Commands:` line, then print the first word on all  following lines, i.e.

```
  build
  bundle
  ...
```

Currently I'm doing

```
docker-compose --help | sed -e '1,/Commands:/d' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

and while this works, I suspect I could do the whole thing with a single `awk`. The closest I've got so far is:

```
docker-compose --help | awk '/Commands:/,0 { print $1 }'
```

But that includes the matched `Commands:` line. Can it be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you mark the presence of your fence, then you can use it to decide to print the next line and after like:

```
awk 'x==1 {print $1} /Commands:/ {x=1}'
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. It looks like I don't even need the `,0` anymore.

Comment: note that `print $1` only prints the first word. use `print` or `print $0` to print the whole line

Answer (score 2):

Note that `1,/Commands:/d` easily translates to `awk` like:

```
awk 'NR==1, $1 == "Commands:" {next}; NF {print $1}'
```

A difference with `sed` is that it will also work if `Command:` is on the first line.

And the `NF {print $1}` can be translated to `sed`:

```
sed -n '1,/^Commands:/!s/^[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/Commands:/,$p' filename | awk 'NR!=1{print $1}'
```